# how to find the solution of a double differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following second order equation:

$y'[x] + xy''[x] = 0$

From Mathematica I know the solution is $y[x] = A+ B \log[x]$ and I know
that through substitution this is indeed the correct answer.

However, I can't find a way of doing this without guessing the solution itself.

I have tried substitution i.e. letting $y=x^k$ and this gives a trivial solution of
$y=0$. I also tried letting $x=\exp[t]$ and this doesn't work either.

Is there an elegant way of doing this? I have looked up some advanced calculus textbook
and couldn't find an example similar to mine.

Comment: These square brackets are confusing. I assume you mean parenthesis.

Comment: yes, such that $y$ is a function of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'+xy''=(xy')'=0$$ integrates as

$$xy'=b$$ or $$y'=\frac bx.$$

After a second integration,

$$y=a+b\log x.$$

---

If this is still "too magical", notice that the equation is of the first order in $y'$. Use $z:=y'$ and solve

$$z+xz'=0,$$ which is separable.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is clear!

Comment: This answer uses the fact that the LHS is in the required form of a derivative using product rule, so it integrates nicely. If this isn't the case for one can use the Integrating Factor method to find out the multiple needed to apply to the LHS to get it into the required form.